# Kusto - Conditional formating in Kusto

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

I have a Kusto Query where the result is in the table format. But when I apply the conditional format it does not highlight the cell with the correct color as per the rule I created.

for example--I have a column with duraion and set the rule as below

```
Green if > 0
Blue if > 1
Yellow if > 5
Red if > 20
```

But I see some of the cell that has value 2.5 is highlighted in Red . where the color should be blue. When I delete the rule for Red, the cell changes to Yellow color. Is there a solution for this or right way to apply rule.Thanks. This is projecting a wrong alert. Thanks for any inputs.

Screenshot of column with formating

[image]
some of the values are in red which should be in blue as per the rules (refer screenshot below)

You can see the rules below
[image]

```
datatable (AvgDuration: string, AvgDurationWin: string, AvgDurationLinux: string, MinDuration: string, MaxDuration: string) [
    "0.0666 s","0.0732 s","0.0525 s","0.015 s","0.684 s",
    "0.0663 s","0.0712 s","0.0535 s","0.015 s","0.851 s",
    "0.0649 s","0.0700 s","0.0521 s","0.014 s","0.674 s",
    "25.050 s","17.614 s","18.428 s","13.133 s","56.284 s",
    "0.0982 s","0.1074 s","0.0805 s","0.021 s","1.078 s",
    "0.0982 s","0.1046 s","0.0814 s","0.021 s","1.041 s",
    "0.0982 s","0.1058 s","0.0813 s","0.021 s","1.106 s",
    "0.0987 s","0.1089 s","0.0814 s","0.022 s","1.039 s",
    "0.0992 s","0.1074 s","0.0817 s","0.022 s","1.032 s"
]
```

Comment: I cannot repro this, can you please attach a screen show of all the rules and the column values

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have uploaded the image in my original question.

Comment: It would really help to repro this if you can include a sample resultset as a datatable. (select the applicable range in the grid, right click and choose "copy as datatable")

Comment: Updated my original questipon with sample data table. When I apply the conditional formating like in the screenshot link, it does not work as expeced. Thanks.

Comment: The data values are strings and conditional formating expects numbers.

Comment: I checked and found out the reason for this. after summarizing , I am converting the numbers to strings to limit the characters for ex - 0.01344566 to 0.0134 also adding S to mention seconds.

below is the query and I need to fix it.

```| summarize AvgDuration = avgif (Duration, Tests == "Success"),
| extend AvgDuration =strcat (substring(AvgDuration10,0,6)," s")```

Comment: Thanks, I added my suggestions in the answer section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your values are string. If you want to calculate it by seconds and have conditional formatting you can do the following:

1. Use the round() function to limit the number of digits after the dot
2. Indicate the unit in the column name

For example:

```
| summarize AvgDurationInSeconds = avgif round((Duration, Tests == "Success"), 2)
```

Comment: Thanks..Just to update below is the Query I used and it works .
```| summarize AvgDuraionInSeconds = round (avgif (Duration, Tests == "Success"), 2)```

Comment: How do you color a column in render columnchart?